# Django static files not loading in production

Tags: django

I always get 404 error in loading static files in an EC2 instance. I have searched for hours and tried to implement various suggestions but nothing worked.

[image]

Following is my configuration of different files:

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block extra_head %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static "ddv_example/ddv_example_1_10.js" %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
```

nginx.conf

```
location /static/admin {
        alias /usr/local/virtualenvs/mysite/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin;
    }

    location /static/rest_framework {
        alias /usr/local/virtualenvs/mysite/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/static/rest_framework;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /usr/local/apps/mysite/src/mysite/mysite/static;
    }


    location /static/ddv_example {
        alias /usr/local/apps/mysite/src/mysite/mysite/static/ddv_example;
    }
```

Any suggestions on what am i missing out ?

Comment: Put `static/ddv_example` above `/static` in nginx configuration.

Comment: did you run `python manage.py collectstatic` command ?

Comment: Did both the above steps. Still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had missed out re-running sudo ./server_setup.sh. The nginx configs will take effect only when the script is re-run.